# Client Server (TCP) Question (Time)

Tags: c#, tcp, connection, client-server

I'm relatively new to C# so please bear with me. I'm working on a client server application (in C#, .NET 4.0) and I don't understand some things completely.

Let's assume that there is an established connection between a TCP server and client. Can (without errors) you *write* to the underlying stream from one endpoint if on the other endpoint *read* wasn't called yet?

If you can, how much time do you have to call *read()* and still get all the data? How much data can be in a buffer and how long does it stay in there if there is some sort of a *buffer*? Which data gets lost if you don't call read for some time (newest, oldest, ... ?)

Can there be problems if you *debug* both client and server application at the same time, can it happen that connection seems to be closed because one application is waiting to make a next step in debug mode?

Thank you for your precious time and answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let's assume that there is an established connection between a TCP server and client. Can (without errors) you write to the underlying stream from one endpoint if on the other endpoint read wasn't called yet?

Yes. the OS has an internal buffer for each socket in it's socket implementation. Everything will be stored until that buffer is full.

> If you can, how much time do you have to call read() and still get all the data? How much data can be in a buffer and how long does it stay in there if there is some sort of a buffer? Which data gets lost if you don't call read for some time (newest, oldest, ... ?)

It all depends on how large the buffer is and how often the other end point sends data to it. You can use `Socket.ReceiveBufferSize` to adjust it.

> Can there be problems if you debug both client and server application at the same time, can it happen that connection seems to be closed because one application is waiting to make a next step in debug mode?

No. TCP connections are always open unless one of the end points closes it. Please keep in mind that other parts of your code can close the connection if you use asynchronous IO and do not break ALL threads in each application.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you maybe know what happens when the buffer is full? New data is lost? Or is the buffer "shifted" and throws out old data to make room for new.

Comment: I haven't found any information about that (and I've never needed to know that either). imho you have the wrong application architecture if you think that it can happen in your application.